# CodeBlocks linker problem when trying to use my library

Tags: c++, codeblocks, lib

So I made a library with 2 simple functions and I wanted to add it to my codeblocks project but when I run it I get the following error: `undefined reference to info::aritmetica::aduna(double, double)`.

What I did: I went to build options>linker settings and added the full path to my library (the name of it is `info_lib.lib`). And I also included the full path in the beginning of the `main.cpp` file (another question, how do I just use the `#include "myfile.h"` instead of adding the full path of the header file?)

main.cpp code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "A:\Programming\info_lib\info_mai_simplu.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    cout<<info::aritmetica::aduna(1,2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is it a `.lib` rather than `.a`? Should be the latter if you're using MinGW.

Comment: I created this library is VS 2019, I didnt used MINGW to build it there, I just use MINGW with codeblocks

Comment: This ain't going to work, you need to recompile the library with MinGW. They are incompatible, except maybe for pure C libraries.

Comment: then how can I compile my library with mingw? I cannot change the compiler for VS 2019

Comment: Do I just use a different IDE? I use codeblocks to compile it?

Comment: IDE doesn't matter, only the compiler matters (MinGW vs MSVC). But yes, you either compile it from CB, or directly from the terminal (using MinGW). Or you can instead use VS for both the lib and the program you're writing now.

Comment: Thank you ! I compiled it with codeblocks and MINGW and it works! But how can I make it so if someone wants to use it they won't have to `#include "full_path_to_the_header"`?  where should they place the header file (except in the project folder itself) so they canacces it without the full path ?

Comment: In the library you don't need to do anything special. It can be placed anywhere, but the user will have to specify the location in their compiler/linker settings. The location can be relative to the project directory.